# Combine these two NPM-projects

Tags: javascript, npm, project, setup-project

There are 2 npm projects - web-api (library) and UI.

The web-api uses gRPC-web to communicate with the backend and then convert it to a simple js object.
In the UI, we use Vue.js and web-api.

**Need: combine these two projects.**

The problem is this. gRPC-web uses the CommonJS style (but Closure, TypeScript can be used). So the generated `*.js` files from `*.proto` will have this style for import - `require ('grpc-web')`; for export - `module.exports = ...`.

But Vue.JS only supports EcmaScript 6 style for import and for export. To edit the generated files with your hands or some other utility is bad (not recommended by the developers).

Answer (score 0):

Imports are not, as of yet, [particularily well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=import) in web browsers; you'll probably need to bundle your own modules in some manner. Most of the popular javascript bundling tools these days will resolve commonjs require statements as well as import statements for you. [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) certainly does, as well as [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) do at least.